# Bootstrap Modal - Default selection of Dropdown

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

In Bootstrap Modal, The default Option is not being displayed.

In the drop down, I am expecting the "Please Select" to be the default choice, whereas It shows as "A" as default.

Here is the HTML code :

```
<div class="modal fade" id="staticBackdrop" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1"
    aria-labelledby="staticBackdropLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="staticBackdropLabel">Add New</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <!-- <div>
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        class="form-control">
                </div> -->

                <div class="mt-3">
                    <select class="form-control"
                        formControlName="ctrlType">
                        <option value="" selected disabled>Please select</option>
                        <option
                        *ngFor="let type of formCtrlTypes">
                            {{type}}
                        </option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div [formGroup]="form">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="form-control-placeholder" for="Name">Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="Name" formControlName="name" class="form-control">
        </div>


        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#staticBackdrop">
            ++ Add
        </button>
    </div>

</div>
```

AND Angular code :

```
export class ExampleComponent {
  public formCtrlTypes = [
    "A",
    "B",
    "C",
    "D",
  ]
  form = new FormGroup({
    name: new FormControl(""),
    formCtrls: new FormArray([])
  })
  addNewFormCtrl() {
    const add = this.form.get('formCtrls') as FormArray;
    add.push(this.fb.group({
    ctrlType: ""
    }))
    }
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }
}
```

Output :
[image]

Where as expectation is to have "Please Select" as Default

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are incorrectly binding a form control to the select element. If you remove the `FormControlName="ctrlType"` from the select element, it will then set the disabled option 'Please Select' as default.

When using the select tag consider using the `(change)` event binding.

example I created here on how to do so:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-oxvygr